# Как реализовать передвижение в игре canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть `canvas`,имеющий размеры *800x600px*

И код генерирующий ландшафт, который выходит из массива содержащего цифры каждого блока. Количество блоков по x и y совпадают с размерами самого `canvas`'a. (отрисованы с помощью `drawImage` с готовым спрайтом.

И теперь я не знаю как реализовать перемещение по этой карте и в вообще работу с ней: чтобы персонаж бежал и появлялись тоже заранее сгенерированные спрайты под ним.

Был бы рад любым примерам и советами как переделать.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Представь, что Canvas - это твоя тетрадь. В ней ты рисуешь человечка и хочешь, чтобы он поскакал. Для этого тебе придется перевернуть страницу и заново нарисовать человечка, но уже смещенного он начальной точки и потом снова и снова переворачивать страницу и заново рисовать человечка, чтобы сделать его подвижным. В канвасе подобная механика и тебе придется каждый кадр заново рисовать, чтобы у тебя человечек бегал. Рекомендую воспользоваться готовыми решениями, чтобы делать игры на html5.